# Is there any version of CvBlobs library which works with cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have just discovered [CvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib#Code%20examples) that can be a bless but it sadly uses IplImage.
Is there any chance that there is a new cv::Mat-style edition I just don't happen to find it?

EDIT:

It turned out that I happened to discover 2 distinct libraries, CvBlobsLib and CvBlobs, yeehaa. :)
I saw CvBlobsLib is less used than cvBlobs, that is NOT on opencv willowgarage but on google code. I welcome answers for both libraries, though, as both work with IplImage. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: I'm talking about [cvBlobs](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) in this answer, sorry that I messed it up with [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib#Code%20examples) ...**

I've been looking for this too, but didn't came up with any library, which uses the new image structure.

But actually you can always do this: `IplImage iplImg = mat;` and just use `&iplimg` wherever you need an `IplImage*`.

**I used [cvBlobs](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) this way successful in a few projects:**

```
#include <cvblob.h>
using namespace cvb;

// load image
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("image.jpg");

// convert cv::Mat to IplImage
IplImage img = mat;

// convert to grayscale
IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(&img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvCvtColor( &img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

// get binary image
cvThreshold( gray, gray, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

// get blobs
IplImage *labelImg = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(gray), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1 );
CvBlobs blobs;
unsigned int result = cvLabel( gray, labelImg, blobs );

// render blobs in original image
cvRenderBlobs( labelImg, blobs, &img, &img );

// *always* remember freeing unused IplImages
cvReleaseImage( labelImg );
cvReleaseImage( gray ); 

// convert back to cv::Mat
cv::Mat output( &img );
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. However, you note that you only to convert gray after thresholding to ipl. And also cvRenderBlobs can be called like &static_cast<IplImage>(mat), not to mention that labelImg be also a mat with this trick.

Comment: I cannot find any of the functions and classes in the documentation and I have figured your code is essentially a c code. :( Which library did you mean in your answer exactly?

Comment: Ah f**k, I messed something up in my head and thought the whole time you were taking about CvBlob. Which is another blob detection library for OpenCV. Please take a look at CvBlobs documentation: http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/wiki/FAQ#3_Using_the_library It's a really helpful lib :)

Comment: thanks :) btw. remember to release labelImg, your example is leaky without it ;) ...that is the drawback of going c. :S

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the real C++ version of @moosgummi's answer looks something like this:

```
#include <cvblobs.h>
using namespace cvb;
using namespace cv;
// load image
Mat mat = imread("image.jpg");

// convert to grayscale
Mat gray; cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// get binary image
threshold( gray, gray, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

// get blobs
Mat labelImg; labelImg.create( gray.size(), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL ); // need to check if IPL_DEPTH_LABEL is the right type...not sure
CvBlobs blobs; 
IplImage iplLabelImg = labelImg; // do not release this!
unsigned int result = cvLabel( gray, &iplLabelImg, blobs );

// render blobs in original image
IplImage iplMat = mat; // do not release this!
cvRenderBlobs( &iplLabelImg, blobs, &iplMat, &iplMat);

// for sake of compatibility with moosgummi:
cv::Mat output = mat;
```

And you need a wrapper class for `CvBlobs` say class `cvb::Blobs` with a lazy_copy_refcounted private CvBlobs data and some conversion operators to const CvBlobs and to CvBlobs. Also needed a wrapper function for cvLabel, `cvb::label()`, which does the castings for us, C++ programmers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have yet to check that those casts work for sure. *Some* cast will eventually work in a wrapper around cvLabel, but if the imagedata in an iplImage gets reallocated, I'm not sure it does not screw the refcounting in the original cv::Mat... Have to be careful, hence the wrappers. I'll post it once Im ready with the wrapper.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. 
Create method for cv::Mat doesn't exist.
 error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::create(cv::Size, long unsigned int, int)’.
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
 error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘const IplImage* {aka const _IplImage*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘unsigned int cvb::cvLabel(const IplImage*, IplImage*, cvb::CvBlobs&)’

Comment: You are right, eventually I did not get down to fully work it out. You need to check to what cv::Mat type IPL_DEPTH_LABEL corresponds. You can take out the static casts and just say `IplImage iplLabelImg = labelImg; IplImage ipl = mat;` and make sure you don't release it. (Hopefully constructing ipl image from a cv::Mat does not clone imagedata.)

Comment: I have changed my answer to point you to the right direction, hopefully. I have not tested it though.