# Object detection in video

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to write a simple object detection that uses OpenCV in C# and a video file. I only need the red box showing that it can track the object and the location

This is what I have so far:

```
//// Background Subtraction
            using (CvCapture capture = CvCapture.FromFile("C:\\opencv\\Movie\\2nd view 6th senario uncompressed.avi"))
            //using (CvCapture sourceSrc = CvCapture.FromFile("C:\\opencv\\Movie\\2nd view 6th senario uncompressed.avi"))

            using (IplImage img = capture.QueryFrame())
            using (BackgroundSubtractorMOG mog = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG())
          //  using (BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2())
            // using (BackgroundSubtractorGMG gmg = new BackgroundSubtractorGMG())


            using (CvWindow windowSrc = new CvWindow("src"))
            using (CvWindow windowDst = new CvWindow("dst"))
            {
                CvBlobs blobs = new CvBlobs();
                var frame2 = new Mat();


                IplImage imgFrame;
                IplImage imgIplFg;
                IplImage imgIplFgDst;

                CvRect[] square = new CvRect[2000];
                int j = 0;

foreach (var item in blobs)
                        {// new
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} | Centroid:{1} Area:{2}", item.Key, item.Value.Centroid, item.Value.Area);

                            imgFrame.DrawRect(item.Value.Rect, CvColor.Red);

                            square[j] = item.Value.Rect;
                            j++;
                            int count = 0;
                            //            // new code
                            //            // To show 2 point sequences
                            //            // using the array to put the images to the matrix 
                            CvPoint[] points = new CvPoint[50];
                            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)

 windowDst.Image = imgFg.ToIplImage();
                            windowDst.Image = imgIplFgDst;

                            Cv.WaitKey(50);

                        }
                    }

            }
            //// ******************

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be improved in two ways: say what the code you have already does and how that differs from what you want it to do. Also, I tried to properly indent the code you posted, but the brace count is way off, so there's something wrong with it on a syntax level.

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with the `blobs` object between creation and iterating over it. Don't you need to detect them first? Looks like `cvLabel` is the function do to it -- [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522797/is-there-any-version-of-cvblobs-library-which-works-with-cvmat) have some c++ code that you can probably go by.